# Convergence and monotonicity of roots of $\frac{1}{1 + x - \exp(-x)} = n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We suppose that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus{0} \quad f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x-\exp(-x)}$ , and $x_n \in ]0;+\infty[$ as $x_n$ is an unique solution of the equation $f(x)=n$ on $]0;+\infty[$.

How can I prove that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is **decreasing** and **convergent**.

Comment: For each $x> 0$ it holds that $f(x)<0$... So you can't find $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f(x)=n$. Maybe you mean $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{1+x-e^x}$?

Comment: @DimitrisDallas sorry I did a mistake it's $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x-\exp(-x)}$.

Comment: @pourjour: By the way, I don't think you are meant to prove that this sequence is boring or single-toned (monotony). I think you probably wanted to say monotonicity. Just fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$g(x) = 1 + x - e^{-x}$$

This is an increasing function such that $g(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$

This shows that for any $n \gt 0$, there is a unique $x_{n} \gt 0$ such that $g(x_n) = \frac{1}{n}$, and, as $n$ increases, $x_n$ decreases, and is bounded below by $0$, and hence is convergent. It turns out that it converges to $0$.